# Windows' MSN Zone internet games will not launch due to error

Tags: windows-xp, application-launch

I keep getting this error when trying to launch Internet Spades on a Windows XP machine:

> Spades is unable to start. Close some other programs and try again, or
>   try reinstalling Spades using Add/Remove Programs in Control Panel.

I used the Add/Remove programs to disable, then enable games. It asked for the Windows XP CD which I put in. Did some stuff like it was working. Still get the same error message.

Comment: Do any of the other games still work?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by this: "...try reinstalling Spades using Add/Remove Programs in Control Panel."?

Comment: Are any of the other MSN Zone games working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution will fix all Windows XP MSN Zone Internet games. As always, first try rebooting the computer. If that doesn't solve the problem, please try the following:

#### How to uninstall and reinstall Windows XP games via Control Panel

1. Clicked the **Start** menu
2. Click **Control Panel**
3. Click **Add or Remove Programs**
4. Click **Add/Remove Windows Components** located on the left side
5. Select **Accessories and Utilities**
6. Click on **Details...**
7. **Uncheck** the box for *Games*
8. Click **OK**

   - *Accessories and Utilities* windows will close
9. Click **Next**

   - *Windows Components Wizard* will close upon completion
10. Click **Finish**
11. Repeat Steps 4 - 10

    - On Step 7: **Check** the box for *Games*

---

If the steps above dont work then try these instructions:

#### Manual install/reinstall option ([*Source*](http://bit.ly/rnsGoc))

1. Insure the following files are at: `C:\Program Files\MSN Gaming Zone\Windows\`

   - bckg.dll
   - bckgres.dll
   - bckgzm.exe
   - chkr.dll
   - chkrres.dll
   - chkrzm.exe
   - Cmnclim.dll
   - Cmnresm.dll
   - hrtz.dll
   - Hrtzres.dll
   - hrtzzm.exe
   - rvse.dll
   - Rvseres.dll
   - Rvsezm.exe
   - shvl.dll
   - Shvlres.dll
   - hvlzm.exe
   - UniAnsi.dll
   - zClientm.exe
   - ZCorem.dll
   - zeeverm.dll
   - ZNetM.dll
   - zoneclim.dll
   - zonelibM.dll
2. Insure these files exist:

   - C:\WINDOWS\inf\IGAMES.INF
   - C:\WINDOWS\Help\bckg.chm
   - C:\WINDOWS\Help\chkr.chm
   - C:\WINDOWS\Help\hrtz.chm
   - C:\WINDOWS\Help\rvse.chm
   - C:\WINDOWS\Help\shvl.chm
   - C:\WINDOWS\system32\zoneoc.dll
3. Edit this file: `C:\WINDOWS\inf\sysoc.inf`

   - `[Components]`
     `...`
     `MSWordPad=ocgen.dll,OcEntry,wordpad.inf,HIDE,7` 
     `ZoneGames=zoneoc.dll,ZoneSetupProc,igames.inf,,7` ***<-- Add This Line***
     `TabletPC=tabletoc.dll,TabletSetupProc,Tabletpc.inf,HIDE,7`
   - ***You only need to add the ZoneGames line. The other lines are there for context.***
4. Restart the computer

*Note: If you are missing any of the files then download [this](http://www.mediafire.com/?n53833glngu6rih) zip file. The zip file is courtesy of Dale Swanson -- the one who is responsible for the above steps. Step are in detail steps for both the experienced and non-experienced users.*

Comment: How does this fix spades? I feel like you copy and pasted this

Comment: It basically removes (or uninstalls) all the games, including spades, then installs them back. As for me copying and pasting, you would be wrong. If you look at most of my answers, I tended to post my answers like this -- very detail. Since I have Windows 7 Ultimate, I wrote these steps up by recreating the steps via **Windows XP Mode**. Please do not assume.

Comment: ... If I use a source from another site or questions, I always add link to the original source of the information within my answer. That can be verify by review my questions. In many cases, I will look for supporting sources to support my answer even if I knew the answer in the first place.

Comment: That's fine, it just looked that way because you didn't really state how this was solving the problem

Comment: Considering that the OP noted that reinstalling games through the `Add / Remove Programs` Control Panel didn't fix the problem, I fail to see how this suggestion, original as it is, will help.

Comment: I was confused by his question. Hence the comment on the question. To me, it was clear if he was asking a question or stating that he tried the step above. Just in case he didn't, posted my this answer.

Comment: Yes, I did try what you are suggesting. But your descriptive step by step should help someone else. So, the solution was actually to reboot my computer. It must have been a memory leak or something. I always forget to restart before trying to fix it any other way. If you could please update your answer to suggest a reboot before trying the steps below, I will accept your answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @zechdc - Rebooting a second time won't help 'clear memory leaks' any more than rebooting once. :)  I trimmed your suggested edit down to just "reboot first", since that was your actual/appended solution. :)

Comment: Added another possible solution. The source is provided. Instead of linking the page as a second option, I extracted the solution. My reasoning was, the post in its original form may be too difficult to understand and follow.